# Cognito Identity using several logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-cpp

I am starting to implement federated authentication with AWS Cognito using AWS C++ SDK.

I want to authenticate a user with Cognito User Pool and Facebook, Twitter, Google.

I understand that I can link several logins under single user identifier (Cognito identityId), but it is possible only when such logins are added manually after first login.

In example, I see scenario:

1. A user is registered using Cognito UserPool.
2. Then, staying authenticated, the user authenticate itself using Facebook. And Facebook tokens can are added to logins.
3. When further retrieving AWSCredentials call processes - the Facebook login will be added to the user identity at Cognito Identity Pool.
4. After, the user can login using UserPool credentials and through Facebook authentication under the same user identityId.

Firstly, I am not sure that my scenario is correct, but it is what I realized after reading many posts here and AWS docs.

And if the scenario is correct, then I am in stuck with another question: how to refresh tokens?

In AWS C++ SDK in order to refresh AWS Credential the call `CognitoIdentityClient.GetCredentialsForIdentity` is used, but it requires to pass user logins.

My more specific question: do I need to pass all logins? Does it require to have all access tokens in the logins no expired?

Answer (score 0):

Adressing your first point, you can use federated identity without using cognito user pool. This means that you can simply autheticate a user directly with facebook, google etc and not add them to user pool. If you do want all users to be there in user pool then you will have to write the code to accept certain parameters from these authentication providers and then add them along with username and password to your user pool.

Now on to your question. To refresh token you have to use [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html). In auth flow you have to pass "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH" and in AuthParameters you pass the refresh token.

Comment: Yes, I am aware on all of this, anyway, thanks. Also, from AWS docs, Cognito links logins implicitly, when they passed to `InitiateAuth`. And my questions is more about accounts linking. I have already used User Pools and refresh tokens successfully. But I am not sure that 1) I can link logins only when I have some valid login, and 2) if then, ie Facebook access token will be expired, - will I be able to refresh AWSCredentials or will need to refresh token? All expired tokens or only some one?